# Can ALSA output sound from a motherboard jack input line to HDMI?

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi

I have a machine installed with [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) and I'd like to use the [motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81M-ITX/?cat=Manual) line input (jack) and redirect sound through the HDMI link. All the other jacks from the motherboard will be unused.

I tried playing with `alsamixer` (booting the machine with a LiveCD since OpenELEC has no ALSA mixer application) but all I can get is sound going out through the output jack. With Kodi I can use any HDMI link I wish as the main output but I have come to wondering if both sound hardware can interact...

Input is made through Intel HDA `Realtek ALC892`. HDMI is an `Intel Haswell HDMI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously you can do it by running a program that reads audio from a capture device and writes it to the HDMI output (potentially through pulseaudio, so you can mix other sounds with it).

I don't have any specific suggestion for you about what program to look for, sorry.

I think it's unlikely that two different cards (the analog codec on the mobo, and the Haswell GPU HDMI) can talk to each other without software intervention.  I wouldn't even be confident about being able to get the Realtek audio hardware to internally send audio from its ADC to its digital S/PDIF output.

Comment: Doesn't sound optimistic but after having searched a bit more I guess I expected such an explanation. Thank you very much for your insights.